# Problem in Translational invariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

In Shankar's QM (second edition, p-282), There are some equations are given, They are following as,

$$T(\epsilon)|x\rangle = |x + \epsilon \rangle$$
where $T(\epsilon)$ is Translation operator.

I understood equation given above, but Shankar says, "X is basis is not unique" then general result should be given as below,

$$T(\epsilon)|x\rangle = e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}|x+\epsilon\rangle \tag{11.2.10}$$

Here what is $g(x)$ ?  Definitely $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}$ is periodic in nature. So how could we relate  this periodic function with the non-uniqueness of basis?

Edit: I know in 7 th chapter of Shankar it's given that basis is not unique, but I don't know that how non-uniqueness of that basis is related to exponential.

Comment: *Definitely $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}$ is periodic in nature.* Not necessarily. Consider the case when $g(x)$ is a constant. Or when it is quadratic in $x$. Or anything other than linear.

Comment: Oh got it, but how this $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}$ is related to non-uniqueness of basis?

Comment: Have you read through Shankar Ch. 7, including the exercises? The full sentence is: "As seen in Chapter 7, the $X$ basis is not unique".

Comment: Yes I know that X basis is not unique, but I did not get how is it related to $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}$? I know it's but how is it related I simply don't know.

Comment: @anbhadane The last exercise in Ch. 7 explains this in detail.

Comment: @probably_someone sorry but can you mention page number, because in my book last exercise is given by, 7.5.4 Thermodynamics 0f oscillator.

Comment: @G.Smith $e^{ig(x)}$ is periodic whenever $g$ is. And a constant $g$ is periodic. The core of your comment is correct however.

Comment: Note that $|x+\epsilon\rangle$ and $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}|x+\epsilon\rangle$ represent the same *state* (both kets belong to the same ray). Is this phase due to the fact that the translation operator acts on kets rather than rays? From Weinberg: *"The unitary or antiunitary operators $U(T)$ corresponding to these symmetry transformations have properties that mirror this group structure, but with a complication due to the fact that, unlike the symmetry transformations themselves, the operators $U(T)$ act on vectors in Hilbert space, rather than on rays."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|x+\epsilon\rangle$ and $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}|x+\epsilon\rangle$ represent the same *state* (both kets belong to the same [ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space#Overview)).

> Here what is g(x) ?

From Shankar (2nd edition), exercise 7.4.8

> This exercise teaches us that the "X basis" is not unique, given a
>   basis $|x\rangle$, we can get another $|\tilde{x}\rangle$, by
>   multiplying by a phase factor which changes neither the norm nor the
>   orthogonality.

Earlier in the exercise, Shankar writes:

> $$|\tilde{x}\rangle = e^{ig(X)/\hbar}|x\rangle =
>  e^{ig(x)/\hbar}|x\rangle$$
>
> where
>
> $$g(x)=\int^xf(x')dx'$$

and then asks you to verify that, in the new X basis

$$P\rightarrow -i\hbar\frac{d}{dx} + f(x)$$

Thus, specifying only that the translation operator $T(\epsilon)$ translates the *state* (ray) from a particle located at $x$ to the state of a particle located at $x + \epsilon$, leaves a degree of freedom since (as written above) $|x+\epsilon\rangle$ and $e^{i\epsilon g(x)/\hbar}|x+\epsilon\rangle$ represent the same *state*.

It must be further specified that the translation takes $\langle P\rangle \rightarrow \langle P\rangle$ to "reduce $g$ to a harmless constant (which can be chosen to be zero)."